# Fortify CI integration

Tags: jenkins, fortify

As part of running the scans from Jenkins build process, FPR files are generated using the sourceanalyzer tool and uploaded to SSC.

What is the best way to review FPR file and stop the build if any errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can check the exit code of `sourceanalyzer` for both the translate and scan phases, if it's non-zero, something went wrong.

---

To specifically check for issues in the *translation*, run:

`sourceanalyzer -b <your_build_id> -show-build-warnings`

You'll have to parse the output to filter out what you consider to be noise and return non-zero to fail the build.
If there were no warnings or errors, there won't be any output from that.

---

In the *scan*:

`FPRUtility -information -errors -project <your_FPR>.fpr`

Again, you'll have to parse out what's of interest. If there wasn't any errors or warnings stored in the FPR, you'll just get:

> No warnings occurred during analysis

---

Lastly, if you want to look for specific types of vulnerabilities that were found, you can use:
`FPRUtility -information -search -query "<search string>"`

Where `<search string>` is a filter you can use in Audit Workbench, e.g. to find SQL injection vulnerabilities, you could specify `-query "category: sql injection", and the output would be something like:

> 72 issues of 1512 matched search query.

Comment: FPRUtility -project DUA.fpr -information -search -query "[fortify priority order]:high"     FPRUtility -project DUA.fpr -information -search -query "[fortify priority order]:critical"   ... using these queries able to fail the build if any high/critical errors. thanks!